# Performace loss for using non-power of two textures

Tags: ios, opengl-es

Is there any performance loss for using non-power-of-two textures under iOS?  I have not noticed any my in quick benchmarks.  I can save quite a bit of active memory by dumping them all together since there is a lot of wasted padding (despite texture packing).  I don't care about the older hardware that can't use them.

Answer (score 0):

This can vary widely depending on the circumstances and your particular device.  On iOS, the loss is smaller if you use `NEAREST` filtering rather than `LINEAR`, but it isn't huge to begin with (think 5-10%).